# Video brush orientation in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to set the video brush (viewfinderBrush) for the rectangle(viewfinderRectangle) fill property.

Using the following composite transform, the preview of the video can be viewed but it looks like mirror reflection. (for eg. If I try to move the finger from left to right, it shows right to left). I also added my xaml code, which has only the rectangle.

```
viewfinderBrush.RelativeTransform =
                      new CompositeTransform() { CenterX = 0.5, CenterY = 0.5, Rotation = 270, ScaleX = -1 };

viewfinderRectangle.Fill = viewfinderBrush;
```

Xaml Code

```
<Rectangle x:Name="viewfinderRectangle" Width="640" Height="480" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

Please let me know, to overcome this issue.

Comment: did you try it without `ScaleX = -1`?

Comment: what do you mean, I asked whether you tried it *without* it

Comment: I am sorry, but if I try without scaleX = -1, it inverts the video (upside down).

Comment: then try adding `ScaleY=-1` or a rotation of 90

Comment: viewfinderBrush.RelativeTransform =
                          new CompositeTransform() { CenterX = 0.5, CenterY = 0.5, Rotation = 270, ScaleY = -1, ScaleX = -1 };   Worked with this transformation. Thanks for your suggestions